# Cannot edit files in IIS localhost server

Tags: iis, localhost, windows-server-2012, access-denied, localserver

I have to edit a website on local server. I use Windows Server 2012 and IIS. When I try to save a modified file I only get "access denied" error. Do I need to shut down the server before making changes and then restarting it or am I missing permissions for example in the wwwroot folder for IIS_IUSRS?

I have never used WS2012 or IIS before.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit files directly in the wwwroot. You need to copy the file/folder out of inetpub to make your edits then paste it back into the wwwroot. This is by design I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do edits directly in the wwwroot files by creating a local user account for myself on the server and giving it FULL access (I am also in the Administrators group - but that was not enough to make it work), then setting the user full access on the SHARE I use to get to the server (via UNC path). Allows edits directly to my live site.